# Google sheets Script Editor Remove UnNeeded Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im attempting to use Google Sheets Script editor to create a script to remove All but the last 10 rows of data.
Close I come is this code with still, no success.

```
function deleteUnNeededRows(startFrom)
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testdoc');
    // get last row index
    var lastRowWithContent = sheet.getLastRow();

    if(lastRowWithContent < startFrom)
    {
        // rows below startFrom are already blank!
        return;
    }
    
    // count total number of rows to be deleted
    // +1 is to include the last row
    var totalRowsToBeDeleted = lastRowWithContent - startFrom + 10;
    
    sheet.deleteRows(startFrom, totalRowsToBeDeleted); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function deleteUnNeededRows(){  
   var startFrom = 1;
   var keep = 10;
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testdoc');
   var nrows = sheet.getLastRow() - startFrom - keep + 1;
   if(nrows>0){
    sheet.deleteRows(startFrom, nrows); 
   }
}
```

**Note that** [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) returns the last row with content. For example if you have 10 columns and the first `10` have last row with content to be `55` but there is a random value in column `20` at the end of the sheet let's say row `900` then `900` will be the last row in your sheet. Be careful with that, otherwise you will need other approach to get the last row with content.

I removed the argument of your function. It is totally fine to use it, but then you have to test this function by calling it from somewhere else. To eliminate the confusion you can test it like that.

Comment: This script executes, but doesn't do anything on the actual sheet...
Do I need to place the sheet ID as well as sheet name here?

Comment: @MattyS check again my answer. Actually how do you run it? I deleted the argument of the function so you can run it directly. If you need the argument there, then you need to call that function from another function. Be careful with that.

Comment: Yes,  `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testdoc');` <-Name of tab executes, but nothing happends. IF I put Name of document I get an error of at line 16 'get last row is null'..

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for your time Marios. Much appreciated!